confused about object type
in the below code fragment gives us this output
Code Fragment:
    let person :object = {name:"Jhon", age:32};     console.log(person);
Output :
    { name: 'Jhon', age: 32 }
My question is ; how it is possible, "person" refferance variable refering an object which does not have any property
l meant "person" refferance variable must refer
to this ==> {} object. Which does not have any property
but when we invoke below code
    **console.log(person);**
it gives us as output   "{ name: 'Jhon', age: 32 }"...
l think "console.log(person)" must give us below output
           {}
Anybody gives me an explanation thanks
l try this
   let person :object = {name:"Jhon", age:32};     console.log(person);
output is
    { name: 'Jhon', age: 32 }
my expectation is output should be
      {}

You are explicitly assigning the value {name:"Jhon", age:32}, so why should it be empty after that?

yes but when we invoke this
console.log(person.name);
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

@SüleymanYalman - True, from a type perspective, all you know about person is that it's an object, you don't know what kind of object it is, so you can't write code relying on a property that may not be there. It happens that the name property is there in the example above, but you've said the type of person is object, not {name: string;}. If you wanted to write code relying on the object having a name property, you'd use a type that said that.


my expectation is output should be {}

First, remember that TypeScript is a type layer on top of JavaScript that doesn't exist at runtime. It can't change values. The value you assigned to person was the object {name:"Jhon", age:32}, so that's what you're going to see when you log it out. TypeScript can't change runtime behavior.
You seem surprised that you can assign that object to a variable of type object, but it's absolutely fine. The object type is for any kind of object. It could be an object with name and age properties, it could be an array, it could be a Date, ... Those are all subtypes of object, and you can always assign a subtype value to a supertype reference. You almost never use object directly as the type of a variable/parameter/etc. (it's just not very useful), you usually use a more specific object type instead with the properties you expect the object to have.
(TypeScript does offer excess property checks that apply in fairly limited situations, where if you assign an object literal to a variable, and the object literal has properties the type of the variable doesn't have, it warns you about that. That's not because it's theoretically wrong [it isn't, it's just assigning a subtype], but because as a pragmatic matter, it's often a mistake by the programmer. But excess property checks don't apply to things typed with the object type, specifically.)
